# Conditionally render wrapping code based on child component

Tags: reactjs

```
const Components = {
  FirstComponent,
  SecondComponent,
  ThirdComponent,
};

//This is component A (parent)
// componentType is a prop

let TimelineContentComponent = Components[componentType];

<TimelineItem>
   <TimelineSeparator>
     <TimelineDot>
       <some content>
     </TimelineDot>
     <TimelineConnector />
   </TimelineSeparator>
   <TimelineContent>
     <TimelineContentComponent />
   </TimelineContent>
</TimelineItem>

//This is FirstComponent

if (<some condition C1 is true>) {
  return null;
}
<div>
  <!-- some code -->
</div>

//This is SecondComponent

if (<some condition C2 is true>) {
  return null;
}
<div>
  <!-- some code -->
</div>

//This is ThirdComponent

if (<some condition C3 is true>) {
  return null;
}
<div>
  <!-- some code -->
</div>
```

As you can see, the child components may render to null in which case I would like not to render the `<TimelineItem>` at all.

Also, the conditions C1, C2 and C3 are different, the conditional logic is known by the child components and I would not like to move this logic to the parent component.

What is the proper way to achieve that with React?

Comment: Could you provide "wrapping code" in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use same condition variable for conditionally rendering component A as well.

//This is component A (parent)

```
if(<somecondition is true>){
return (
    <TimelineItem>
       <TimelineSeparator>
         <TimelineDot>
           <some content>
         </TimelineDot>
         <TimelineConnector />
       </TimelineSeparator>
       <TimelineContent>
         <B />
       </TimelineContent>
    </TimelineItem>
    )
    else return (
<div>something else</div>
   }
```

Comment: Maybe his condition is using a `state` that's only accessible within the Child component?

Answer (score 1):

If you think in how React works, this is somewhat of a paradox.

The children are rendered only after the parent is rendered. So a parent can't depend on its children to render because when the children are evaluated the parent has already rendered!

So in order to control the parent, you need to know beforehand about the various conditions C1, C2 etc. You need to elevate those conditions to a shared state.

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const [ state, setState ] = useState({
   child1: true,
   child2: true,
   ...
  })
  
  const handleConditionChange = (child, condition) => { 
    setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      [child]: condition
    })
  }

  const [ forceRender, setForceRender ] = useState(true);
  useEffect(()=>{
    if (...) setForceRender(true) // you need to check this periodically in SOME WAY
  })

  // just an example of how you can use the children state to conditionally render the parent
  if ( forceRender || (state.child1 && state.child2 ...)) {
    return ( 
    ...
     <Child1 handleConditionChange={handleConditionChange}/>
     <Child2 handleConditionChange={handleConditionChange}/>
    ...
    ) 
  } else return null
}

const Child1 = (props) => {
  const [ condition, setCondition ] = useState() // controls if component renders or not

  useEffect(()=>{
    setCondition(<some condition>) // your boolean logic goes here
  })

  useEffect(()=>{
    props.handleConditionChange('child1', condition) // when condition changes, tell the parent
  },[condition])

  return condition 
    ? <component code>
    : null
}
```

This way you still keep the logic inside each child component but now you're reporting to the parent in order for it to make use of that information as well.

**Edit**: Added reset condition `forceRender`. You need some sort of reset condtition periodically, otherwise after the first time `Parent` ever returned `null`, you'd reach a dead end since its children would never be evaluated again.